# Can't completely avoid redirection through HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, redirect, http-post, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-302

Eventhough I have set to not follow redirects:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

I still can't get my `POST` request to work. I get response code: 302 (it means the website offers me redirection) and I think this is the reason because everything works perfectly with other websites that doesn't redirect. How to completely avoid redirection so to make my `POST` request to work?

Comment: POSTs are not followed, protocol-changes (http -> https) neiter.

Comment: So there is no way to avoid it?

Comment: You can manually follow the redirects. `conn.getResponseCode() == 302` then read `Location` header and create a new request.